# Localization doesn't work for german?

Tags: windows-phone-8, localization

I googled a lot and did these changes to my project:

.csproj:

```
<SupportedCultures>
  en-US;de-DE;ru-RU;
</SupportedCultures>
```

WPAppManifest.xaml:

```
<DefaultLanguage xmlns="" code="en-US" />
  <Languages xmlns="">
    <Language code="en-US" />
    <Language code="de-DE" />
    <Language code="ru-RU" />
  </Languages>
```

And of course I have AppResources.de-DE.resx, AppResources.en-US.resx, AppResources.resx and AppResources.ru-RU.resx.

When I set the phone to russian, the app starts in russian as expected. But that doesn't work with german. I checked the AppResources-files many times. It's all in there, they should work. but somehow de-DE doesn't get recognized.

Tried the same with simple "en;de;ru;" with the same result.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

I found this tutorial: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-8-Localization.aspx and they also use "de". So I changed all appearances of those strings to "de", "en" and "ru". Still russian works, german appears as english - the default language =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, stupid, but it was in the project's properties. For some reason the defaultlanguage was set to german.

Still think that it's in confusingly many places. I'll summarize them for everybody who might need it in the future:

- project's properties, 1st tab "supported cultures" and "asseblmy information" button!
- WPAppManifest.xaml view Code
- AppResources.xx.resx
- inside AppResources files the "ResourceLanguage"-tag should be set to "de", "en", "fr" or whatever.

That's many places and I hope I didn't forget one O-o